# how to filter(search) name from api data in angular without using pipe

Tags: angular

I want to search zone name coming from api without using pipe.
Here is my html code

```html
<div class="search">
  <input #name type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
  <button (click)="searchText(name.value)" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </button>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped tabs">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of h; let i = index">
      <td>{{i+1}}</td>
      <td>{{data.zone_name}}</td>
      <td>{{data.zone_id}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

below is my ts code for search

```js
searchText(name: string){
   this.zoneName = name;
   this.http.get('http://192.168.8.219:8833/zonedata/'+ 
   this.zoneName).subscribe((obj)=>{
      console.log(obj);
   })
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(obj);` return?

Comment: What is your question? What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Note that passing arbitrary text in the URL as you're doing isn't safe.

Comment: console.log(obj) shows the response coming from backend. I want to display search name on table.

Comment: when i click submit button then searchText function is called and whatever the value we are giving in input that value goes to api and search in database. If that name is present then it will display that name only on table

Answer (score 1):

Using observables only would be way easier to read, test, understand and less error prone too

```
class YourComponent {
  public zoneName$ = new Subject();

  public searchResult$ = this.zoneName$.pipe(
    debounceTime(200),
    switchMap(zoneName =>
      concat(
        of([]),
        this.http.get(`http://192.168.8.219:8833/zonedata/${zoneName}`)
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Then in the view just use the async pipe:

```
<button (click)="zoneName$.next(name.value)" type="submit">
```

and

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of searchResult$ | async; let i = index">
```

Also, doing the above and using `debounceTime` lets you trigger a search only when the user has finished typing, not on every key stroke.

The concat is used to reset the result first as soon as it changes and then broadcast the new value